# How to show PDF from .net maui app on Windows

Tags: maui, .net-maui, maui-windows

I am just trying to show a PDF file from my .NET MAUI application on Windows and it is giving me the error below.

"System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'An error occurred trying to start process 'C:\Users<username>\Documents\helpfile.pdf' with working directory 'C:\WINDOWS\system32'. The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.'"

My code is below.  It has worked in a WPF app but won't work here.

```
        Process.Start("C:\\Users\\<username>\\Documents\\helpfile.pdf"); // removed the username here and above in error message
```

also tried: (getting helpfile.pdf from install directory)

```
        string _asmPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

        int lastIndex = _asmPath.LastIndexOf('\\');
        string helpfilePath = $"{_asmPath.Substring(0, lastIndex)}\\helpfile.pdf";

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(helpfilePath);
        Process.Start(startInfo);
```

and I get a similar error:
"System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'An error occurred trying to start process 'C:\Projects\SnapSignalTel\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\AppX\helpfile.pdf' with working directory 'C:\WINDOWS\system32'. The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.'"

How can I open this PDF document (helpfile.pdf) in a MAUI app on Win10?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What happens if you set `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true` ?

Comment: I tried this and it works also! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [Launcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/launcher?tabs=android)

```
await Launcher.Default.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest("Some Title", new ReadOnlyFile(filepath)));
```